# How can I convert this select statement to functional form?

Tags: kdb

I am having a couple of issues to put this in a functional format.

```
select from tableName where i=fby[(last;i);([]column_one;column_two)]
```

This is what I got:

```
?[tableName;fby;enlist(=;`i;(enlist;last;`i);(+:;(!;enlist`column_one`column_two;(enlist;`column_one;`column_two))));0b;()]
```

but I get a `type` error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the following function, adjust from the `buildQuery` function given in the whitepaper on [Parse Trees](https://code.kx.com/v2/wp/parse-trees/#appendix). This is a pretty useful tool for quickly developing in q, this version is an improvement on that given in the linked whitepaper, having been extended to *handle updates by reference* (i.e., `` update x:3 from `tab ``)

```
\c 30 200
tidy:{ssr/[;("\"~~";"~~\"");("";"")] $[","=first x;1_x;x]};
strBrk:{y,(";" sv x),z};
//replace k representation with equivalent q keyword
kreplace:{[x] $[`=qval:.q?x;x;"~~",string[qval],"~~"]};
funcK:{$[0=t:type x;.z.s each x;t<100h;x;kreplace x]};

//replace eg ,`FD`ABC`DEF with "enlist`FD`ABC`DEF"
ereplace:{"~~enlist",(.Q.s1 first x),"~~"};
ereptest:{((0=type x) & (1=count x) & (11=type first x)) | ((11=type x)&(1=count x))};
funcEn:{$[ereptest x;ereplace x;0=type x;.z.s each x;x]};
basic:{tidy .Q.s1 funcK funcEn x};
addbraks:{"(",x,")"};

//where clause needs to be a list of where clauses, so if only one whereclause need to enlist.
stringify:{$[(0=type x) & 1=count x;"enlist ";""],basic x};
//if a dictionary apply to both, keys and values
ab:{$[(0=count x) | -1=type x;.Q.s1 x;99=type x;(addbraks stringify key x),"!",stringify value x;stringify x]};
inner:{[x]
    idxs:2 3 4 5 6 inter ainds:til count x;
    x:@[x;idxs;'[ab;eval]];
    if[6 in idxs;x[6]:ssr/[;("hopen";"hclose");("iasc";"idesc")] x[6]];
    //for select statements within select statements
 //This line has been adjusted
    x[1]:$[-11=type x 1;x 1;$[11h=type x 1;[idxs,:1;"`",string first x 1];[idxs,:1;.z.s x 1]]];
    x:@[x;ainds except idxs;string];
    x[0],strBrk[1_x;"[";"]"]
    };
buildSelect:{[x]
    inner parse x
 };
```

We can use this to create the functional query that will work

```
q)n:1000
q)tab:([]sym:n?`3;col1:n?100.0;col2:n?10.0)
q)buildSelect "select from tab where i=fby[(last;i);([]col1;col2)]"
"?[tab;enlist (=;`i;(fby;(enlist;last;`i);(flip;(lsq;enlist`col1`col2;(enlist;`col1;`col2)))));0b;()]"
```

So we have the following as the functional form

```
?[tab;enlist (=;`i;(fby;(enlist;last;`i);(flip;(lsq;enlist`col1`col2;(enlist;`col1;`col2)))));0b;()]

// Applying this
q)?[tab;enlist (=;`i;(fby;(enlist;last;`i);(flip;(lsq;enlist`col1`col2;(enlist;`col1;`col2)))));0b;()]
sym col1     col2
----------------------
bah 18.70281 3.927524
jjb 35.95293 5.170911
ihm 48.09078 5.159796
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Glad you were able to fix your problem with converting your query to functional form.

Generally it is the case that when you use parse with a `fby` in your statement, q will convert this function into its k definition.  Usually you should just be able to replace this k code with the q function itself (i.e. change `(k){stuff}` to `fby`) and this should run properly when turning the query into functional form.

Additionally, if you check out https://code.kx.com/v2/wp/parse-trees/ it goes into more detail about parse trees and functional form.  Additionally, it contains a script called `buildQuery` which will return the functional form of the query of interest as a string which can be quite handy and save time when a functional form is complex.

Answer (score 0):

I actually got it myself ->

```
?[tableName;((=;`i;(fby;(enlist;last;`i);(+:;(!;enlist`column_one`column_two;(enlist;`column_one;`column_two)))));(in;`venue;enlist`venueone`venuetwo));0b;()]
```

The issues was a `()` missing from the statement. Works fine now.

**if someone wants to add a more detailed explanation on how manual parse trees are built and how the generic `(k){}` function can be replaced with the actual function in `q` feel free to add your answer and I'll accept and upvote it